# Can't update my state for no apparent reason with Redux Toolkit

Tags: typescript, redux, state, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I am new to Redux Toolkit, and I guess I am missing something even it looks like I did everything right.

Here is my test case:

```
import { ReduxStore } from '../../../react-view/main'
import { configureStoreWith } from '../../../app/store'
import { Dependencies } from '../../../app/dependencies'
import { InMemoryIdProvider } from '../../../infrastructure/idProvider/InMemoryIdProvider'
import { InMemoryRandomDiceProvider } from '../../../infrastructure/randomDiceProvider/InMemoryRandomDiceProvider'
import { rollDice } from '../diceSlice'
import { Die } from '../entities/Die'
import { IdProvider } from '../ports/IdProvider'
import { RandomDiceProvider } from '../ports/randomDiceProvider'

function dieDataBuilder() {
  return new Die('uuid', {
    isHeld: false,
    value: 0,
  })
}

describe('Generate Random Dice', () => {
  let store: ReduxStore
  let dependencies: Dependencies
  let idProvider: IdProvider
  let randomDiceProvider: RandomDiceProvider

  beforeEach(() => {
    idProvider = new InMemoryIdProvider()
    randomDiceProvider = new InMemoryRandomDiceProvider()
    dependencies = {
      idProvider: idProvider,
      randomDiceProvider: randomDiceProvider,
    }
    store = configureStoreWith(dependencies)
  })

  it('should generate 10 random dice', () => {
    const expectedDice = Array(10).fill(dieDataBuilder())

    store.dispatch(rollDice())
    const generatedDice = store.getState().dice.dice

    expect(generatedDice).toStrictEqual(expectedDice)
  })
})
```

Hence the following SUT (System Under Test):

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Dependencies } from '../../app/dependencies'
import { Die } from './entities/Die'
import { GenerateRandomDiceUseCase } from './usecases/GenerateRandomDiceUseCase'

type ExtraDependencies = {
  extra: Dependencies
}

export const rollDice = createAsyncThunk<Die[], void, ExtraDependencies>(
  `dice/rollDice`,
  async (thunkAPI, { extra: { randomDiceProvider, idProvider } }) => {
    const dice = new GenerateRandomDiceUseCase(
      randomDiceProvider,
      idProvider,
    ).execute()
    return Promise.resolve(dice)
  },
)

export const initialState = {
  dice: [] as Die[],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
}

export const diceSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'dice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(rollDice.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload)
      state.dice.concat(action.payload)
      return state
    })
  },
})
```

`console.log(action.payload)` prints what I expected, i.e. an array of 10 dice.

```
    console.log
      [
        Die { id: 'uuid', props: { value: 0, isHeld: false } },
        Die { id: 'uuid', props: { value: 0, isHeld: false } },
        Die { id: 'uuid', props: { value: 0, isHeld: false } },
        Die { id: 'uuid', props: { value: 0, isHeld: false } },
        Die { id: 'uuid', props: { value: 0, isHeld: false } },
        Die { id: 'uuid', props: { value: 0, isHeld: false } },
        Die { id: 'uuid', props: { value: 0, isHeld: false } },
        Die { id: 'uuid', props: { value: 0, isHeld: false } },
        Die { id: 'uuid', props: { value: 0, isHeld: false } },
        Die { id: 'uuid', props: { value: 0, isHeld: false } }
      ]
```

I tried to push, concatenate, return state, not returning it (as Immer is supposed to allow mutation and figure it out).

But no matter what, the result of my unit test keep being:

```
  Generate Random Dice
    ✕ should generate 10 random dice (109 ms)

  ● Generate Random Dice › should generate 10 random dice

    expect(received).toStrictEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 72
    + Received  +  1

    - Array [
    -   Die {
    -     "id": "uuid",
    -     "props": Object {
    -       "isHeld": false,
    -       "value": 0,
    -     },
    -   },

[...],

    -   Die {
    -     "id": "uuid",
    -     "props": Object {
    -       "isHeld": false,
    -       "value": 0,
    -     },
    -   },
    - ]
    + Array []

      38 |     const generatedDice = store.getState().dice.dice
      39 |
    > 40 |     expect(generatedDice).toStrictEqual(expectedDice)
         |                           ^
      41 |   })
      42 | })
      43 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/core/dice/usecases/GenerateRandomDice.spec.ts:40:27)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.435 s, estimated 4 s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/core\/dice\/usecases\/GenerateRandomDice.spec.ts/i.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Full repo here : https://github.com/amehmeto/HexaTenzies

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it.

1st/ You were right on the fact that I needed await.
2nd/ I removed the return
3rd/ I use push and loop over the array instead of trying to use concat

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(rollDice.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      action.payload.forEach((die) => state.dice.push(die))
    })
  }
```